# Get objects which have NO relation to the current object

Tags: django, foreign-keys, filtering

I am currently workong on an update for a X-Y matrix of subscribers (customers) on different products. Originally it's a matrix containing approx. 500 customers and 24 products. To speed up the rendering, we implemented some filtering methods (A-Z / buisness type filtering, valid/expired, etc).

Another request was to be able to filter on customers which have no subscriptions at all, like Customer C and D in the table below.

```
|           | subsc A | subsc B | subsc C | subsc D | subsc E |
|-----------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|customer A |  valid  |    -    |    -    | expired |    -    |
|customer B |    -    |  ended  |    -    |  valid  |    -    |
|customer C |    -    |    -    |    -    |    -    |    -    |
|customer D |    -    |    -    |    -    |    -    |    -    |
|customer E | expired |    -    |  valid  |    -    |    -    |
```

The subscription table has looks like the following (simplified):

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    startDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    endDate = models.DateField()
    blank=True, null=True)
    ended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is there any django-magic to get the list of customers who have NO subscription listed? If not, any suggestions on a clean method to get to the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `count` of `subscriptions` per `customer`, then then `.filter` the `customers` without `subscriptions`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
unsubscribed = Customer.objects.annotate(
        subscription_count=models.Count('subscription')
    ).filter(subscription_count=0)
```

Another way (which should be faster) is to use the `__isnull` notation against the reverse relation of the `FK`. Here is how:

```
 unsubscribed = Customer.objects.filter(subscription__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Using this example throws in into an infinite loading state as soon as I hit the filter button. I cannot access ipdb or anything else to debug. Any suggestions why this could be happening?

Comment: Hmm, it could be a slow query. Can you run something like `show full processlist;` (this is for MySQL), to see if any queries are being executed during the loading state. Then, if thats the case, we can start searching for a way to optimize it.